# Custom short commands to open apps

Tags: spotlight, customization

Is it possible to create custom short commands to run apps and open folders, to be called in Spotlight?

I mean, I'd like to create custom commands so I just open Spotlight (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>) then run things like:

- **`c`<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to run `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`
- **`s`<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to run `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`
- **`g`<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to run `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app="https://mail.google.com"`
- **`w`<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to run `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app="https://web.whatsapp.com"`
- **`work`<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to open the folder `/Users/myusername/Documents/workspace/`
- **`serv`<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to run something in the Terminal

And so on... I think you know what I mean!

Thanks!

---

*PS: I am coming from Windows, where I would: add a folder to the `%PATH%` variable, throw shortcuts in this folder dragging and dropping icons with the right mouse button, then rename them shortcuts to the alias I want. Then it is just <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to run my stuff. Trying to figure out a equivalent on Mac. Adding a folder to `$PATH` and creating executable scripts in it didn't work.*

Comment: Seems like a lot of steps to me.  I have function keys 1 to 9 all assigned to apps.  Press F4 and I get my favorite web browser.  I use Keyboard Maestro.  It's paid, but doing it the macos way was too hard for me to figure out. see my write up here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361174/44531

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight can't do this. You can probably hack something using AppleScript, Automator etc, but it might be easier to use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) which allows for this and a lot of other interesting things.

[image]

For your scenario it will actually learn which application you pick from the list and offer it as the default selection after a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Automator is what you want - for example, when you open automator, choose 'Folder Action' to set up an automation for your 'work' folder.

Some of it will require learning a bit of AppleScript.

Comment: Why the minus out of interest?

Comment: You could significantly improve the question by explaining in detail how Automator etc can be used to implement the things the question asks for.